# Rails Runner scripts with double dash arguments throw Rackup error after Rails 7 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following an upgrade to Rails 7.0.6 all the rails runner scripts we have in the script directory which accepted double dash style (like `--year`) arguments now throw an error regarding Rackup. Where Rackup appears to think that those arguments are meant for it and it doesn't recognize them.

```
invalid option: --year
Usage: rackup [ruby options] [rack options] [rackup config]
```

Rails Runner apparently doesn't relay those arguments to the script now. I can call them without arguments and with them as long as they don't use standard argument syntax. Use single or double dash and it doesn't work.

I am calling these scripts with this basic format

```
bundle exec rails r script/quote_report.rb --year 2023
```

Using something like

```
bundle exec rails r script/quote_report.rb year 2023
```

Does work

There is a solution that I would rather not use and that is to do

```
bundle exec rails r script/quote_report.rb -- --year
```

A solution which preserves the original way these scripts were called would be preferable.

Comment: Rackup (which starts the Rack server) shouldn't be involved at all in this process. Does this same behavior happen for all scripts? Try writing a simple `script/puts.rb` which just contains `puts "hi"`, and see if `bundle exec rails r script/puts.rb --year 2023` has the same result.

Comment: Yup does the same thing.

Comment: I amended my post to show that if I do bundle exec rails r script/myscript.rb -- --year it works. Which is something I've had to do before with things like our npm setup to get arguments to the testing system to tell it to rewrite snapshots. I would just prefer not to have to do that.

Comment: `--` is a pretty idiomatic way of separating out "arguments for the main command" vs "arguments for the secondary command", so if that's the new behavior of Rails then it's got a lot of precedent behind it. After all, otherwise a `-e` flag would be ambiguous between specifying the environment or being passed to your script. So, my suggestion for you would be to either embrace your inner zen and accept it, or write a custom `bin/runner` script which invokes the passed-in script the way that you'd like.

Comment: Unless my docker container is completely hosed and when I rebuild it it goes back to normal. I suppose yes. It's weird that it's `Rackup` when that has to do with the server but if it's not a screwed container or weird config I guess it's time to embrace it.